# Log when tomcat binds port 8080

Tags: tomcat7

I have a feeling my app takes a few seconds between saying it finished initializing (Server startup in XXXXX ms by Catalina) and when I can ping my servlets.

Is there a log/listener I can switch on to see when the binding occurs?

Furthermore, is there another process, which I might be unaware of, that happens between the Server startup and the webapp being fully available?

I'm using Tomcat 7.0.42 on Ubuntu.

Comment: What's the question here? When does Tomcat bind port 8080, or when is my application ready?

Comment: the binding. I'll clarify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the port is bound before any applications are started. Look for something like this in the logs (this is from Tomcat 8):

```
08-Oct-2013 11:23:20.809 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

What you really want to know is when does Tomcat start accepting connections on that port. That happens a little later. Look for this in the logs:

```
08-Oct-2013 11:23:22.212 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Comment: The `Starting ProtocolHandler` is one line before `Server startup in` meaning even after it is written, I still have a few seconds without working servlets.

Comment: Define not working. A few seconds delay before you get a response or do you get a conneciton refused?

Comment: I get a delay. a few seconds wait time for the first response. Also when accessing static content

Comment: Servlets are loaded lazily. JSPs are compiled on first access. Try using load-on-statup for Servlets and pre-compiling JSPs.

Comment: Static content should be quick immediately unless you have very large files and very slow disks.